# TYPO3 GIFBUILDER with image from FLUID

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I want to use the GIFBUILDER to make an image with an overlay. The image should therefore be delivered via FLUID.

This is what I have so far:

FLUID

```
<f:for each="{product.images}" as="image">
   <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.overlay" data="{image: image.uid}" />
</f:for>
```

TypoScript

```
lib.overlay = IMAGE
lib.overlay {
    file = GIFBUILDER
    file {
        XY = 300,500
        format = jpg
        quality = 80
        10 = IMAGE
        10 {
            file.import = {field:image}
            file.import.insertData = 1
            file.import.treatReferenceAsId = 1
        }
        20 = TEXT
        20 {
            text = Copyright
            fontColor= #dddddd
            fontSize = 30
            offset = 100,100
            align = left
            antiAlias = 1
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment, I only get a white Background with the label Copyright on it. However if I do somethinge like

```
10 = IMAGE
10.file = fileadmin/path/to/file
```

all works just fine.

So my question is: How do I pass the Image from FLUID correctly to TypoScript?

And as addition to this, how do I pass a value from the Contentelement via FLUID to make the overlay text dynamic too?

Best regards and Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

output of {image} (one image):
[image]

Comment: Can you post the results of `<f:debug>{image}</f:debug>` inside your for loop?

Comment: @RudyGnodde I've updated the question with a screenshot of the debug output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
10 = IMAGE
10 {
    file.import = {field:image}
    file.import.insertData = 1
    file.import.treatReferenceAsId = 1
}
```

with

```
10 = IMAGE
10 {
    file.import.field = image
    file.treatIdAsReference = 1
}
```

`treatReferenceAsId` should be `treatIdAsReference`. It's also a property of `file`, not of `file.import`. I'm not sure why `file.import = {field:image}` and `insertData = 1` doesn't work, but `file.import.field = image` does. It's cleaner anyway, which is why I tried it.

You might also want to add a width and height or maxW and maxH to the image, unless you're 100% sure they're always 300x500 pixels.

Comment: Seems like the problem is somewhere else, since this does not work either

Comment: I tried it and updated my answer with additional edits